# Filling in null values with the values from the most recent data - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

[image]

For the above table, what would be a sensible SQL server solution to fill in the null values with the most recent preceding data i.e. the data from October 16th?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `cross apply`:

```
select t.date, coalesce(t.value, t2.value), coalesce(t.value2, t2.value2)
from t cross apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.value is not null and t2.date < t.date
      order by t2.date desc
     ) t2;
```

If the unfilled in values are only for the most recent rows, then this is much more efficient:

```
select t.date, coalesce(t.value, t2.value), coalesce(t.value2, t2.value2)
from t cross join
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.value is not null
      order by t2.date desc
     ) t2;
```

If you want to update the values, then a correlated subquery might be the simplest:

update t
set value = (select top (1) t2.value
from t t2
where t2.value is not null and
t2.date <= t.date
),
value2 = (select top (1) t2.value2
from t t2
where t2.value2 is not null and
t2.date <= t.date
)
where value1 is not null or value2 is not null;

Answer (score 0):

Using Subquery:

```
 SELECT Date
,ISNULL(Value, (SELECT TOP 1 Value From Temp T1 WHERE T.Date > T1.DATE AND T1.Value is not null)) AS Value 
,ISNULL(Value2, (SELECT TOP 1 Value2 From Temp T1 WHERE T.Date > T1.DATE AND T1.Value2 is not null))  AS Value2
FROM Temp AS T
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

Comment: Another person answered with cross apply that's why I have added another way.